# Google Maps marker clusters by nested category?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Lets say i have an array of markers like this:

```
[{id:1, label:'Country1', parentId:null},
{id:2, label:'Country2', parentId:null},
{id:3, label:'City1', parentId:2},
{id:4, label:'City2', parentId:2},
{id:5, label:'House1', parentId:4},
{id:6, label:'House2', parentId:4}]
```

Each marker has its lat and lng coordinates.
The problem is that usnig standard marker cluster, groups markers by there lat and lng position.
I basicly don't want to groupe them but to categorise them by current zoom level or some thing like that.

Is this even posslible to do?

Lats say that current map view is whole world. At this zoom I want to show only top level markers like Country 1 and 2. When I zoom in I want to see City 1 and 2 but not Country 1 and 2. This should go unlimited levels deep.

So each level should have max and min zoom level at which it is displayed?

Please give me some options for this.

The whole purpose of this is tho show organization assets on map. This assets are nested in category like city > building > floor > assets...

Comment: Do you need to use the standard marker cluster for this, can you not just set a minimum and maximum zoom property on the markers and then display them when the zoom of the map in in that range [Some zoom levels set by google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Zoomlevels)?

Comment: This was my first option. But I'm sure there are better solutions for this or not? Currently I'm using google.maps.OverlayView for creating custom marker that supports standard marker properties.

Comment: None that I can think of, I can't see anything too wrong with this, unless you have some markers with overlapping zooms, the code by @Dinesh should be a good starter

Comment: Sounds like you want the [MarkerManager](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markermanager)

Answer (score 1):

You can create event listener on zooming. Based on zoom levels you can use `setVisibile` property to show/hide

for example :

```
/* Change markers on zoom */
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    // iterate over markers and call setVisible
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setVisible(zoom <= 15);
    }
});
```

Comment: I probably should define some types of objects and set max and min zoom level on those. Then each marker would be of some type that has its visibility property allready set. This would minimize error on user defining zoom levels on there own.

Comment: @MatejKrhin exactly.